# according to this code how java know where to start

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, point

i am trying to figure out how Java know where to start according to this Graphics code when i run this code it showing ball moving from top to down but i can't understand why from top and why from this place and i know that java use *math.random()* to set the value but how it set the x and y
while when i trying to put any random number by my self it gives number that is bigger than the width it self (i am taking exactly about pos.x and pos.y)

this the first class

```
package movingball;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

/**
 *
 * @author isslam
 */
public class Ball {
    private final int RADIUS = 10;
    private final Point pos;
    private final Color ballColor = Color.red;
    private final int CHANGE = 3;
    private final int height,
    width;

    public Ball(int frameWidth, int frameHight) {
        width = frameWidth;
        hight = frameHeight;

        pos = new Point();
        pos.x = (int)(Math.random() * (width - RADIUS)) + RADIUS;
        pos.y = (int)(Math.random() * (height / 2 - RADIUS)) + RADIUS;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(ballColor);
        g.fillOval(pos.x - RADIUS, pos.y - RADIUS, 2 * RADIUS, 2 * RADIUS);
    }
    public void move() {

        if (pos.y < height - RADIUS) {
            pos.translate(0, CHANGE);
        }

    }

}
```

this is the second class

```
package movingball;
import java.awt. * ;
import javax.swing. * ;
/**
 *
 * @author isslam
 */
public class ClassOfMoving extends JFrame {
    protected final int FRAME_WIDTH = 240;
    protected final int FRAME_HIGHT = 320;
    private final Ball myBall = new Ball(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

    public ClassOfMoving(String title) {
        super(title);
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(ClassOfMoving.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        myBall.paint(g);
    }

    public void move() {
        while (true) {
            myBall.move();
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the main class

```
    package movingball;

/**
 *
 * @author isslam
 */
public class MovingBall {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassOfMoving is = new ClassOfMoving("isslam");
        is.setVisible(true);
        is.move();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, You seem a bit confused.

This line does the actual moving.

```
pos.translate(0, CHANGE);
```

The `Ball` position `pos` is translated with `CHANGE` pixels in the y-dimension. `CHANGE` is defined as 3 somewhere else. Top-Left position is normally (0,0) on a computer screen, so the pos.y will increase with 3 and the `Ball` will move downwards by three pixels<sup>*</sup>.

`Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1. The following line positions the ball on a random position between 0+r and width-r.

```
  pos.x = (int)(Math.random() * (width - RADIUS)) + RADIUS;
```

If you want to specify a specific position, set pos.x directly instead of replacing Math.random().

The y-position is defined as the top half half of the window because the max value is defined as `height/2`.

`pos.y = (int)(Math.random() * (`**`height / 2`**`- RADIUS)) + RADIUS;`

*:<sub>The coordinate system of a computer display is flipped upside down compared to the conventional coordinate system where positive is up. The reason is perhaps to be found in how old cathode ray tubes paints (from top left) and also how line numbers increase downwards on line printers, and also later in character based display systems.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Independently these two classes when compiled and executed in an app won't do anything as it doesnt have either main method or static block. but if you are using it in conjuction with any framework , jars or any additional code, that might be helping execute it by means of creating their objects. Hope it answers.

Comment: i need explanation for the code not how to fix the code sorry